# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header completely ignored by FireFox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, webforms, cors, response-headers

I set up my website (running IIS8.5) to send the response header for CORS to a subdomain off my main domain and the header response is getting to Firefox just fine. All plug-ins, ad-blockers, etc, are disabled and I can see the header in the DOM inspector.
I've tried:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://services.mywebsite.com
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://services.mywebsite.com
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "null"
```

I've verified the SSL Certificate is working just fine (it's a wildcard cert for *.mywebsite.com from Sectigo and I've verified that the entire certification path is working properly)

There are no other response headers except for: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN  ,however, I removed it with the same result.
The site predates CORS by years (ASP.NET Webforms) and there are no other settings I can find that would prevent Firefox from acknowledging this response header.

I've read dozens of posts here (usually someone had a self-signed cert or forgot something) but am at a loss on what is wrong?

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://services.mywebsite.com/api/geodata/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

It's absolutely NOT MISSING!  WTF Firefox?

Pulling hair out here. Anyone?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://services.mywebsite.com
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Wed, 27 May 2020 08:28:05 GMT
```

Someone else suggested adding a CORS module to IIS.  I did, then added to my web.config file the following (in system.webserver section):

```
<cors enabled="true">
    <add origin="*" allowed="true" >
        <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
    </add>
</cors>
```

No Joy! Same message from Firefox (and Chrome) - both browsers completely ignore this directive.  Could this be a bug in Mozilla?

-------------------- more info ---------------------------------

I think the problem is with the following jquery script with my CHAT (which is doing the calling to the api).  It's worked for 12 years (and still works on old versions), so I'm looking to see what's been deprecated. I suspect that SignalR may be the issue and confusing the browser(s) - since SignalR is making the request (not sure, though -just guessing now). Sorry for not mentioning this sooner.

```
        $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function () {
            var existingChatId = getExistingChatId(chatKey);
            $.get("https://services.mywebsite.com/api/geodata/", function (response) {
                myHub.server.logVisit(document.location.href, document.referrer, response.city_name, response.region_name, response.country_name, existingChatId);
            }, "json");
        })
        .fail(function () { chatRefreshState(false); });
```

------------------- after using wildcards for CORS headers --------------

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcU2l0ZXNcaWNhcnBldGlsZXMyXFdlYlxzaWduYWxyXHN0YXJ0?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Date: Sun, 07 Jun 2020 10:31:35 GMT
```

Still no joy - Headers are there. Must be a bug in ASP.NET webforms, IIS, SignalR  (please note this is NOT MVC).  Time to upgrade this site for this client. No one supports webforms anymore, anyway - it's dead.

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Or use the **Log XMLHttpRequests** option in the Console to have the request and response details logged to the console. If Chrome doesn’t seem to show you the HTTP status code, then try with the Network pane in Firefox devtools. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: 200 
I can see the response header (why I'm baffled)

Comment: I added the response info in my first post.  As you can see, it's all there, no errors.

Comment: Just a note: This is not just a CORS problem, but a CORB problem. What's the point in security if you can't make AJAX calls to anyplace but your own domain?

Comment: I hope this article helps: https://cmatskas.com/signalr-cross-domain-with-cors/

Comment: It would, but it's for MVC.  I think the other guy is correct - you can't use SignalR with webforms for cross-domain.  You can wildcard all the headers - makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do cross domain requests with SignalR and be CORS compatible. There is no way around this problem. 
Just move your service to your www.yourwebsite.com  and save your hair!

Answer (score 1):

You can install `cors` dependency:

"Microsoft.AspNet.Cors": "6.0.0-rc1-final"

Add the CORS services in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
}
```

And enable it for specific domain:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(builder =>
        builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com"));
}
```

Another option is enable `cors` for a specific method:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")] 
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Or enable it for an specific controller:

```
[EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

If you're using MVC 3, and you have the file `Global.asax` you can use the method:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowedOrigin); 
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST");
}
```

If you're using `WebApi`, you might use:

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`

And register the `cors` using:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // New code
    config.EnableCors();
}
```

And:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // My methods...
}
```

Or enable it for whole the project:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://example.com", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
}
```

**ASP.Net web forms**

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Also try:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","*");
```

Try adding directly in web config:

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: How would this be done with an old webforms application?  It's pre-MVC.

Comment: @MC9000 I updated my answer with asp.net web forms. The way to do it is updating the web config file. Is the answer is useful, pleas upvote it!!!

Comment: I went to check. I tried this already with no luck. Oh well.
CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  yada - The thing is it's 100% there in the header!!!! From IIS, from any webpage at all - the header is friggin showing up in Chrome's diagnostics. This makes no sense at all.  Perhaps the javascript is the problem. (like I said before, this USED to work just fine until CORS became a thing - so the script is just fine)

Comment: I added proof that the headers are making it to the browser to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `app.UseCors()` in your middleware pipeline, before `app.MapSignalR()`?

You can start with `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)` to check if it'll work and then add your own domain.

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
app.MapSignalR();
```

Comment: webforms, not MVC. Thanks

Comment: @MC9000 Could you share the code where you are adding the SignalR on the server?